# Converting UNIX timestamp to a local time of a region?

Tags: sql, presto

How can I convert a field that is a unix time to local time of a region?

```
Timestamp 
1507576891
1507582204
1508777161
```

I want to when I select convert to local time of Europe/Berlin?

I am trying

```
Select cast(from_unixtime(time, Europe/Berlin) as date)
```

but am missing something, as I want result to be time like ***2019-12-12 16:32:00***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Combine [`from_unixtime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime) and [`at_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#at_timezone):

```
presto:default> SELECT at_timezone(from_unixtime(1507576891), 'Europe/Berlin');
                 _col0
---------------------------------------
 2017-10-09 21:21:31.000 Europe/Berlin
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cast. Use convert_tz for convert to the time zone of your choice.

`SELECT convert_tz(from_unixtime(eater_request_epoch), '+00:00','+01:00') as 'localdate'`

Comment: Where to I convert to the timestamp that I want for the region? @jared for Europe/Berlin

Comment: The target timezone is the third argument. +0 implies that the dates are saved in UTC. `CONVERT_TZ (date, from_tz , to_tz)`

Comment: So if I want to make it for timezone, Europe/Paris for example ? @jared

Answer (score 0):

Europe/Berlin timezone is GMT+1 so you could do something like this

```
select convert_tz(from_unixtime(1508777161), @@session.time_zone, '+01:00') as 'Europe/Berlin'
// 2017-10-23 17:46:01
```

**More useful:**

to get the current time:

```
select convert_tz(now(), @@session.time_zone, '+01:00')
// 2019-12-16 09:33:36
```

and formatted:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CONVERT_TZ( NOW( ) , @@session.time_zone , '+01:00' ) , '%b %d %Y %h:%i:%s %p' )
// Dec 16 2019 09:34:30 PM
```

To get the diff-time from a timezone (ex: Indochina Time GMT + 7) with your current mysql time:

```
select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(), @@session.time_zone, '+07:00'));
```